# How to delete this 2d dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
bool **arr=new bool* [row];
for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    arr[i]= new bool[column];
}
```

I want to delete this dynamic array because it cause a problem with my RAM.

Comment: As a side note you should probably replace `9` with `row` to allocate each row, not just the first 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just delete in the reverse order it was allocated:

```
for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    delete [] arr[i];
}
delete[] arr;
```