# How to delete a 2D dynamically allocated matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, 2d, dynamic-allocation

I have a whole program that is working with pointers, dynamically allocating and arrays, etc.

My last function that was given to me is a function to delete matrix.
Here is the given information:

```
/*
  Deletes a two dimensional dynamically allocated matrix
  -- rows: The number of rows in the matrix
  -- **matrix: the matrix to be deleted
*/
void delete_matrix(int rows, char **matrix)
{
  delete[] matrix;
}
```

My question is, is this right? and also why is a value for rows being passed in?

Comment: How was it allocated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete this 2d dynamic array in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711893/how-to-delete-this-2d-dynamic-array-in-c)

Comment: Don't use new and delete. Use an STL container that does de-allocation when the container's destructor is invoked, or else use some smart pointer.  In modern C++, new and delete are mainly for writing custom allocators or other low level library code.

Answer (score 0):

With dynamically allocated arrays, you can think of them as arrays of arrays. What is happening behind the scenes is that there is a pointer to an array of pointers, and you have to free the memory for each of the pointers down the line, not just the main one. Long story short, you need the number of rows because you need to delete each row in the array to avoid a memory leak before you delete the main array. 
It should look something like this:

```
/*
  Deletes a two dimensional dynamically allocated matrix
  -- rows: The number of rows in the matrix
  -- **matrix: the matrix to be deleted
*/
void delete_matrix(int rows, char **matrix)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
  {
     delete matrix[i];
  }

  delete[] matrix;
}
```

**Edit:**
The above is assuming that you used `new` to create the array. If you used `malloc` instead, you would need to put `free(matrix)` instead of `delete[] matrix`and put `free` inside the for() loop as well instead of delete.

Comment: This is not necessarily correct, it depends how the matrix was allocated, which we don't know.

Comment: Is this what you are asking for? char **matrix; //pointer to a matrix
  matrix = new char*[row][col];

Comment: @SpencerApel -- You really should be specifying these details in your original question, not as a response to an answer.